# Should the website main page be cached?

Tags: html, performance, caching, http-headers, pagespeed

To my knwoledge, caching should be ONLY enabled for static contents of website, and we use no-cache for dynamic pages. The website main page is the most dynamic page as contents are regularly updated. Strangely, I found that major websites set a short cache maxage for the main page too. Google set 3 seconds, stackoverflow 21 seconds.

More strangely (to me), when analyzing the performance by `WebPageTest.org`, it considers the main page as a static content, and expects a long cache lifetime. For example, you'll receive a FAILED notice for short 21s cache lifetime of `stackoverflow.com`. Check [HERE](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120326_JR_3QH91/1/performance_optimization/#cache_static_content). Even for 2 hours, you'll receive WARNING.

How the main page and other dynamic pages should be cached?

Comment: "Yes, we cache!". Jokes aside, I've personally always leaned towards caching as aggressively as content allows.

Comment: Very hard to answer, as this would be very different for each website and solution. Plus even if there isn't any expiration set on the content (which I presume is what WebPageTest checks) there could be plenty of caching on the serverside, which is usually a lot more important.

Comment: @alex - on the other hand, regulary updated pages, should not be cached, when data has a real-time value.

Comment: I think it is more Important to set correct cache headers for your static page content like JavaScript, CSS and Images. You also should compress and concat your CSS/JS...

Comment: @alex I appreciate the usefulness of caching, but how the visitors would get new updates. Consider stackoverflow, refreshing the main page to see new questions: here we are always 21s late, but the point is that 21s is not a long lifetime for cache, what if caching the main page for 2 hours?

Comment: 21s is not a long lifetime for small sites. For hightraffic sites it's not that small because it decreases a huge amount of server work.

Comment: 1. how? people refresh the page within 21s? why re-visit in this short time? if they refresh to see update, we do not give them what they need 2. How caching small websites with a few hours? the site will look dead in daytime!

Comment: @Ali: 1. Apparently they do; because new questions can pop up even in such a short time. There's a balance between "give them what they need" and "the server will catch on fire if we do that, and we don't have $ infinity.00 to get another one - especially when this 21 sec latency does the trick, while not reducing usability considerably" - this needs to be weighed for every page individually.

Comment: @Ali: 2. Depends whether that page has any changing content - if it does, then of course it doesn't make sense to set few hours' expiration; OTOH, if it's e.g. a product announcement or contact info, without any changing elements (e.g. discussion), then why not set it to few hours' expiration? It's not very likely that these change very much from one minute to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you should cache everything including the dynamic pages as well. Static pages/resources can be cached with a very high max-age as generally they wouldn't change that often and even if they do change, you could change the request url (by adding QS) to avoid the cache entry.
Caching dynamic pages is a bit tricky as the content changes quite frequently. If possible you should try implementing If-Modified-Since for the dynamic pages, where in the If-Modified-Since is the timestamp of the last time your page or the sub-section was changed. Generally, If-Modified-Since would be a DateModified timestamp column in your database for that particular entity. If your page is being composed of multiple db entities, then If-Modified-Since would be the min of DateModified for those entries. Implementing If-Modified-Since is actually a bit of hassle so a lot of people just leave their dynamic pages as is but do keep in mind it is really helpful if your page/site is pretty popular and crawled by SEs quite often.

Answer (score 6):

Any page should be cached if it's useful to do so - whether static or dynamic. Not caching dynamic pages becomes suicidal when running a high-traffic site, as the unnecessary repeated requests will bring the site to its knees.

Of course, it all depends on the *expected* update frequency, which will differ not only from site to site, but also from page to page: if your "about us" page might change once a week, there is no point in making it expire in 1 minute; OTOH, if the frontpage changes every second, it may be useful to set its expiration time to 21 seconds, as the update latency <1 min is acceptable, yet the 20 seconds where a refresh doesn't necessarily send a HTTP request are quite useful for lowering load.

In other words, there is no hard rule, handed down on stone tablets from Mount Sinai, saying "Thou Shalt Cache The Front Page For One Day", nor "Thou Shalt Not Cache Dynamic Content" - it depends very much on the specific situation of a site.

Answer (score 2):

Cache whatever you can on the server - menus, header and footer regions, banners. On the client-side, cache the HTTP resources (JavaScript, CSS and images).

If the page is dynamic then of course you can't cache it for 7 days, and yes, this would make it slower than a site that was doing that. However, these are examples of the trade-off between features and speed.

As the owner of the site, *you need to make the call where the optimum user experience is* - no automated test is going to tell you that.